# Split a String into a String and an int in Java

Tags: java, string, split

For a string containing multiple characters in the beginning and multiple numeric at the end, how to separate the string in two parts, first part to be stored as a `String` and the second part to be stored as an `int`.

The Strings are like `DRR2110012, SRR211001, ABCDEFG1`, 
and i want to separate the ASCII part and store it in another `String` variable and the digits stored in another `int` variable for each string using Java.

I know I can split a string like this:
`array = "1,2,3,4".split(',');`
But this doesn't help since I don't have a separator.

Comment: `split` takes regex

Comment: You should look at regex

Comment: You need to use split and then cast the part you want to integer.

Comment: @SadiqAli what would you split on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split using regex in the following way.

```
String str = "DRR2110012";
String[] part = str.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
System.out.println(part[0]);
System.out.println(part[1]);
```

Comment: If a string like "ABC123DCE" then this regex will not work.